# Translation works only in preview

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have installed the translation package for drupal 7 on https://localize.drupal.org/translate.

Almost everything works fine, but when i add an article, the translation is only happening in the preview. 
When I show a preview of the article, everyting is in Dutch, but when i actually post the article, it changes back to English.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured language detection at `admin/config/regional/language/configure`?  Assuming that URL is enabled there, try viewing your newly created article at
http://example.com/nl/node/1234
instead of
http://example.com/node/1234.